# Convert Pandas Series from String to Float

Tags: python

I have a pandas series, called `cue`, that contains `NaNs` and numbers that are being stored as `Strings`. Some of the items have two numbers, separated by a comma.

```
26                                           NaN
27                            0.8192939758300781
28         0.3346419334411621, 0.950833797454834
29       0.36624598503112793, 0.9343879222869873
```

I am trying to convert the strings to float variables, and ultimately keep only the first value if there is more than one, so I can do math on them. I have tried:

```
cue=cue.cue.applymap(float)
cue=pd.to_numeric(cue, downcast='float', error='ignore')
cue=cue.astype(float)
cue=cue.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

but to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas what's going wrong and how I can get this to work?

Comment: first you will need to [split](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) the strings with multiple numeric values before pasing it to `to_numeric`

Comment: That did it! Wonderful!